# Python asn1tools library issues and error

Tags: python

I have installed asn1tools library from below link. After running the example provided in the link im facing the below issue. Can any one help me in solving the issue.

Link : https://github.com/eerimoq/asn1tools

$ python question.py

## Error:

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asn1tools/parser.py:875: SyntaxWarning: Cannot combine element of type  with ParserElement
  + actual_parameter_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the pyparsing dependent library which i was having it was the older version. After updating to latest version it is working as expected.